# Save edited data to firebase using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, reactfire

I am creating an app where the user data are registered using reactjs in frontend and firebase as a backend. I could save data to firebase. I could edit and delete the data but could not saved edited data to firebase. What should I do to edit data? I used `child_changed` but still did not work.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        userInfo:userInfo
      }
    this.userRef = new Firebase('https://***.firebaseio.com/users/');
    this.createUser = this.createUser.bind(this);
    this.saveUser = this.saveUser.bind(this);
    this.deleteUser = this.deleteUser.bind(this);

  }

  loadData(){
    this.userRef.on('value', snap => {
      let userInfo = [];
      snap.forEach( data => {
        let userData = data.val();
        userData.id = data.name();
        userInfo.push(userData);
      });
      this.setState({ userInfo });
    });

    this.userRef.on('child_removed', (dataSnapshot) =>{
        delete this.state.userInfo[dataSnapshot.key()];
        this.setState({ userInfo: this.state.userInfo });
    });

  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.loadData();
  }

  createUser(user){
    this.userRef.push(user);
  }

  saveUser(oldUser, newUser){
    console.log('olduser',oldUser);
    console.log('newuser', newUser);
    // TODO - optimize this code
    const foundUser = _.find( this.state.userInfo, user =>
        user.name === oldUser.name
    );
    const foundContact = _.find( this.state.userInfo, user =>
        user.contact === oldUser.contact
    );
    const foundAddress = _.find( this.state.userInfo, user =>
        user.address === oldUser.address
    );
    const foundEmail = _.find( this.state.userInfo, user =>
        user.email === oldUser.email
    );
    const foundUsername = _.find( this.state.userInfo, user =>
        user.username === oldUser.username
    );
    const foundPassword = _.find( this.state.userInfo, user =>
        user.password === oldUser.password
    );
    console.log('foundUser', foundUser);
    console.log('foundUser.name',foundUser.name);
    foundUser.name = newUser.name;
    foundContact.contact = newUser.contact;
    foundAddress.address = newUser.address;
    foundEmail.email = newUser.email;
    foundUsername.username = newUser.username;
    foundPassword.password = newUser.password;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch id as you have saved it in loadData function. So you can do this

```
saveUser(oldUser, newUser){
    console.log('olduser',oldUser);
    console.log('newuser', newUser);
    // TODO - optimize this code
    const foundUser = _.find( this.state.userInfo, user =>
        user.name === oldUser.name
    );
    const foundContact = _.find( this.state.userInfo, user =>
        user.contact === oldUser.contact
    );
    const foundAddress = _.find( this.state.userInfo, user =>
        user.address === oldUser.address
    );
    const foundEmail = _.find( this.state.userInfo, user =>
        user.email === oldUser.email
    );
    const foundUsername = _.find( this.state.userInfo, user =>
        user.username === oldUser.username
    );
    const foundPassword = _.find( this.state.userInfo, user =>
        user.password === oldUser.password
    );
    console.log('foundUser', foundUser);
    console.log('foundUser.name',foundUser.name);
    foundUser.name = newUser.name;
    foundContact.contact = newUser.contact;
    foundAddress.address = newUser.address;
    foundEmail.email = newUser.email;
    foundUsername.username = newUser.username;
    foundPassword.password = newUser.password;
  }
const editUserRef = new Firebase('https://***.firebaseio.com/users').child(oldUser.id);
console.log('edit',editUserRef);
editUserRef.update(foundUser);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to docs: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/
  var ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog");

```
//suppose you have similar kind of data in your data base which was created like this

var usersRef = ref.child("users");
usersRef.set({
  alanisawesome: {
    date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
    full_name: "Alan Turing"
  },
  gracehop: {
    date_of_birth: "December 9, 1906",
    full_name: "Grace Hopper"
  }
});

//then to change data 

usersRef.child("alanisawesome").set({
  date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
  full_name: "Alan Turing"
});
usersRef.child("gracehop").set({
  date_of_birth: "December 9, 1906",
  full_name: "Grace Hopper"
});

//remember that using 'set' causes overwrite data at that localtion to avoid this you can also use 'update' . like if your db looks like this

{
  "users": {
    "alanisawesome": {
      "date_of_birth": "June 23, 1912",
      "full_name": "Alan Turing",
      "nickname": "A Machine"
    },
    "gracehop": {
      "date_of_birth": "December 9, 1906",
      "full_name": "Grace Hopper",
      "nickname": "A Grace"
    }
  }
}


//then you can do this

usersRef.update({
  "alanisawesome/nickname": "Alan The Machine"
  "gracehop/nickname": "Amazing Grace"
});
```